# I cannot import the java.applet and java.awt package in my eclipse ide

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I add a package, it tells me that the package is not accessible.
For example, I imported the applet package, I gives me an error telling that, `java.applet` is not accessible.

[image]

Comment: Are you on Java 11 or later? It is removed from JDK.

Comment: Yes, I am using JavaSE 12

Comment: those pacages do not exist in java 12

Comment: then is there a way to run it

Comment: See https://openwebstart.com/